# Limit content size by character or word in database

Tags: php

I am not talking about the_excerpt() or the_content() output limit. I am talking about the actual content size limiting.
I am using scraper to create posts from external source and link them with external source. I don't want to scrape full content and make my database heavy, so just want to store a part of that content limited to 155 character.
I know I have to modify the scraper though.
Just want to know if I can do it just by using any wordpress built in function that automatically cut down the content size then will insert to the database.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: WordPress doesn't _have_ a scraper. What is this scraper you're using? A plugin?

Comment: yes, using a plugin